# How do I enable a component of a game object when the player collides with a trigger?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game where you have to get from point A to point B without hitting any obstacles. Some obstacles are moving and some are not. I decided to add a trigger in one of my levels that would enable two obstacles' scripts that would make them move. This is the script that is attached to the trigger:

```
 private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    GameObject.Find("Obstacle (10)").GetComponent<MovingObjects>().enabled = true;
    GameObject.Find("Obstacle (9)").GetComponent<MovingObjects>().enabled = true;
}
```

For some reason, this code along with the method do not seem to work. Nothing happens when the player passes through the trigger. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the [Collision matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html)

**Collision** events (like [`OnCollisionEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html)) are **not** thrown on a Collider marked as `isTrigger`.

---

Note that also afaik [`OnTriggerEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html) would only be called on the object which is **not** the trigger.

Comment: Oh, I see. I should have used OnTriggerEnter instead of OnCollisionEnter. Thanks.

Comment: @ClinsBER `OnTriggerEnter` would only be called on the object which is **not** the trigger ;)